# YouTube video insert fails with 401 Unauthorized youtubeSignupRequired

Tags: youtube-api

I'm uploading videos to many customers using Google API v3 with PHP client lib, it works for most of them so I guess the issue is not in my code.
For the customers that fail, it always fails, so I believe the problem is with their authentication, however, for these customers I do get categories list with no problem, it's just the video upload that failed.
That made me think it's because of the scopes I used during the authentication, but I used the same scopes for all my customers, those that work and those that don't.

Any idea?

Thanks,
Tan-Tan

Answer (score 2):

A couple of years ago, YouTube accounts changed and became integrated with Google+. After that point, all new accounts were actually Google+ accounts with a linked YouTube channel; however, YouTube accounts that were created before that changeover needed to manually log in and link their YouTube account to their Google+ account. When you try to use the YouTube API to upload a video, if they have one of these legacy accounts that they haven't manually linked, you'll get the error message that you're experiencing.

There's no API call to do the linking for them; so if your app gets that message, you'll have to redirect them to http://m.youtube.com/create_channel and have them link their accounts.